Can one TVS array such as SRV25-4 from Protek provide both common-mode and differential-mode protection for Ethernet Phy?
I am trying to add protection against ESD, electrical fast transients and cable discharge events in front of an Ethernet Phy, and believe that TVS arrays such as SRV25-4 from protek and RClamp2574NQ from Smetech can do the job. Those TVS arrays share a schematic like the following:

But I have a few questions on how to implement the circuit:

Is common-mode protection necessary particularly when PoE is involved?

In the datasheet of RClamp2574N, only differential-mode protection is illustrated as below:

Also in an earlier version of datasheet for RClamp3374N, it is stated that:

In a typical Ethernet application, these pins (PIN3&8) as well as the tabs should be left floating (i.e. not connected to ground).

On the other hand, the application note from Microchip, the vendor of a popular Ethernet Phy, the following protection scheme is recommended:

It is stated that at a minimum, differential-mode protection by DBI is required, which seems to indicate that differential-mode protection is more important. But common-mode protection by DSE (and Rp) can be also helpful although not as important.
Meanwhile, in an answer to related question, one very reputable user stated that:

do not put any protection that providrs a DC path that to local ground.

My understanding is, DSE will actually provide path to local ground once over the clamping voltage.
I generally just go by the application note from vendor. But we have had some trouble using NUP2202W1, and there seem to be contradicting ideas on whether common mode protection is needed or harmful. So hopefully I can get some clarification here.

Possible/How to provide both differential-mode and common-mode protection with one TVS array assuming common-mode protection is necessary or at least not harmful?

In the datasheet of SRV25-4, the following scheme is recommended for common-mode protection:

My question here is, does such a scheme also provide differential-mode protection? I tend to believe the answer is yes, because the electrical connection between two signal traces in each differential pair is still there. But I don't want to lose differential-mode protection while trying to add common-mode protection which seems not as important.

A minor question, can we not include landing pads for top and bottom center pads on PCB? With landing pads for those two center tabs in the way, it is very hard to route traces if possible. To me, there seems to be no way to route unbroken trace between PIN1&10, or PIN2&9, and so on. There is just not enough clearance between traces and landing pads for those center pads.

So please advise.
Thanks,
ZL

